# Getting Exception Using Firebase in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-crash-reporting

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process TestChartApp.TestChartApp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

this is my code i am using

```
FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

try
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {   
    FirebaseCrash.Report(ex);
    }
```

I am new to implement firebase crash reporting i am trying to implement crash report but it is throwing an error. please help me how can i solve that.

Comment: Review the logcat output and make sure you are not getting: **`[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`** If so, make sure that your `google-services.json` is assigned the build action of `GoogleServicesJson` and that your application package id matches the one that you assigned in the Google Dev. Console

Comment: try using your application context, it also gives you lesser chance on leaking your activity

Comment: @SrinivasCh Glad to help, I created an answer from my comment

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Review your logcat output for `FirebaseInitProvider` tags, if you are getting:

**`[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`**

Then the two major things to check:

- Make sure that your **`google-services.json`** is assigned a **build action** of **`GoogleServicesJson`**
- Check that your application package name matches the one that you assigned in the Google Dev. Console

A successful FirebaseApp registration will result in the following logcat:

**`FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful`**

Answer (score 4):

After assigned the build action as **GoogleServicesJson** its working.

Answer (score 3):

Try entering the following in MainActivity.cs after the LoadApplication call.

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Android.App.Application.Context);
```

Answer (score 3):

The resolution for me was *toggling* the BuildAction for the google-services.json to GoogleServicesJson.

Even though the google-services.json properties showed BuildAction set to GoogleServicesJson, I was still having the error "*Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first*".

I was able to resolve this issue by setting BuildAction to "None" then setting it back to "GoogleServicesJson". When I got latest version from source control the BuildAction must not have carried over to my local copy (although it showed as such).

Comment: Worked for me too, thank you for saving me potentially hours off headache