# Not receive fcm notification when app is closed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Hello I am trying tyo implement FCM in xamarin forms app.
i Installed **Plugin.FirebasePushNotification** Plugin

i implement refresh token class

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

and this class for receive notification but not get notification when app is close

```
  [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
        public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
        {
            const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

            // [START receive_message]
            public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
            {
        }
    }
```

and i used this payload

> {   "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",   "notification"
>   : {
>       "body" : "great match!",
>       "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"   } }

Comment: If your app is in debug mode you need to reopen once & close. Than try sending notification.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 notification receive when app open if closed not received

Comment: Is your app being developed in debug mode? if yes than after opening app, once again & close it. Than send notifications.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 not work

Comment: You can try to sent `data` in place of `notification` in payload & check.

Comment: Run your application in release mode and then try to push notification.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT app closed the then not receive notification in release mode

Comment: Hello @JuniorJiang-MSFT i used this payload `{
 "to" : "token",
 "data" : {
 "body" : "data match!",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark"
 }
}`

work perfect but if app initialize and close app, then send notification from postman notification not receive. if one time open app and after close app then send notification from postman, notification received.

Comment: If you want to handle notification when the application is backgrounded you should send `data message` and use `onMessageReceived` method.Changing `{ "to" : "token", "notification" : {..}` to `{ "to" : "token", "data" : {..}` .Not using notification .

Comment: Your problem maybe not the type of notification.Later I will update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Official document,`FirebaseMessaging` has method of `subscribeToTopic` .

> **[public Task subscribeToTopic (String topic)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#subscribeToTopic(java.lang.String))**
>
> Subscribes to topic in the background.
>   The subscribe operation is persisted and will be retried until successful.
>   This uses a Firebase Instance ID token to identify the app instance and periodically sends data to the Firebase backend.

Here is a official sample for [Android FCM Remote Notifications](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Firebase/FCMNotifications/).After testing this project,If not subscribing notification, notification will not receive when app stopped.

You can have a try.Code as follow when App load:

```
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("news");
```

Comment: Hello @Junior
i received notification via Refresh token not topic so any solution for refresh token

Comment: Do you mean that not receiving in `OnTokenRefresh`?Maybe this is another question.If answer be helpful,you can mark it accepted to close question and reopen another question about `Refresh token`.^.^

Comment: If want `OnTokenRefresh` getting called first need `MyFirebaseIIDService` be called.Here is a good discussion about this.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770907/ontokenrefresh-never-called-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: Hello @Junior i receive notification in release and debug mode and background and foreground, but if i debug application then close debug and send notification, notification not receive after click app icon and open app then close app and send notification notification received **Conclusion**: Debug app close debug, close app, then send notification, notification not receive after then open app and close app, send notification, notification received.

Comment: When click `closing debug` ,this killing the `PID` of app.Then will not receivce notification,service of app are not runing.Suggest that testing notification using the normal interface action to click to close the app, so you can receive notifications, if you have already subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I added `OneTimeWork` with `Result.retry` and added `setBackoffCriteria` to 30 seconds to ensure `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled()`.

If the result is `false`, I run it again with `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(). setAutoInitEnabled(true)`.

Sorry if my english is so bad, because I use Google Translate.