# Push Notification with AppCenter when the app is closed in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I'm implementing `Push Notification` in my app with `AppCenter`. In UWP I created a background service to receive message when the app is closed. I'm trying to do the same with `Android`.

In `Android` project I created a `IntentService` to initialize the `Push` from `AppCenter` but it doesn't work.

```
[Service]
public class PushNotificationService : IntentService
{
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
       if (!AppCenter.Configured)
        {
            Push.PushNotificationReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                new NotificationHelpers().ShowNotification(
                                                   e.Title, e.Message, e.CustomData);
            };
        }
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, 
                             [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return StartCommandResult.StickyCompatibility;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
    }
}
```

Also I added in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application>
    <service android:name="PushNotificationListener" />
</application>
```

What is the correct implementation for `Android`? Is there anything to add in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Where you start the service?

Comment: The first time is when the application starts

Comment: When application starts to start this service,the service just run once.When application is closed,service if not running nothing can happen.

Comment: What is the correct implementation then? I can't find an example. Thank you in advance

Comment: When you start the service, you need to add a thread to ensure that your service is always running. At the same time, according to your logic, if the notification is sent regularly, the time timer is set in the thread, and the notification can be sent when the time arrives.

Comment: Have you referred to this official document?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/android).Here is a dicussion about Firebase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366064/not-receive-fcm-notification-when-app-is-closed/54434868#54434868) .